# Rank-1 correction of matrix exponential

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-physics

I need to approximate the following in $O(d)$ time for $d\times d$ diagonal $A$ and rank-1 $B$
$$u^T \exp(-A+B) v$$

Here $u,v$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R^+}^d$, $A,B$ are positive semi-definite and $B$ is relatively small

The following approximations take $O(d)$ to compute and get me within factor of 2 of true value on sample data

- set $B$ to 0
- truncate Zassenhaus [formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#Zassenhaus_formula) at first term

However, adding more terms from the Zassenhaus expansion seems to make the approximation worse, any tips?

<sup><sub>[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/mathoverflow-DPR1-approx.nb)</sub></sup>

Comment: How is your title correct, what is the matrix that receives a rank-1 update?

Comment: the argument of the matrix function. IE, I can compute $f(X)$ cheaply, and need to compute $f(X+rank1)$ where $f(X)=u^T e^X v$

Answer (score 4):

There is work on low-rank updates of matrix functions, for instance this one:

*Beckermann, Bernhard; Kressner, Daniel; Schweitzer, Marcel*, [**Low-rank updates of matrix functions**](https://doi.org/10.1137/17M1140108), SIAM J. Matrix Anal. Appl. 39, No. 1, 539-565 (2018). [ZBL1390.15024](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1390.15024).

It could be a useful starting point if you wish to explore in that direction.